# Note 5 Android 6.0.1, photo import Windows, PTP does not limit folder access to camera photos

Tags: usb, photos, file-transfer

I have a Note 5 running Android 6.0.1 when I try to import photos using Photos in Windows 10 it finds all of the image files on the phone.  This is not affect by choosing PTP or MTP in the USB settings on the phone.  Trying on different PC running Windows 7 has the same result.  To me this seems like an issue with the USB Setting on the phone for PTP not limiting the PC's access to only the photo folder.  It seems like I have not had this issue in the past unless I'm completely "mis-remembering".
I've seen this question asked before but the only solution seems to be to manually move over photos using windows explorer.  Is this really the only solution?  By not using the photo import option on Windows you are loosing the ability to auto-rotate, easily organize folders, name files, and only sync new images, to name a few.
I would really appreciate any help anyone has on this.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking?